# Destructor and erase for shared pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

As far as I know destructor is called when an element is erased from container, please correct me if I'm wrong..But **Destr X** prints shouldn't appear before **after erase**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct X 
{
    X()
    {
        std::cout<<"Contr X"<<std::endl;
    }
    ~X()
    {
        std::cout<<"Destr X"<<std::endl;
    }
};

using Xptr = std::shared_ptr<X>;

int main()
{
    
    std::shared_ptr<X> x = std::make_shared<X>();
    Xptr x2 = std::make_shared<X>();
    std::vector<Xptr> v;
    v.emplace_back(x);
    v.emplace_back(x2);
    v.erase(v.begin());
    std::cout<<"after erase\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `shared_ptr` in the vector *is* destroyed when you erase it, but the `X` that it enjoyed sharing still has an owner (i.e. `x`). A shared object isn't destroyed until all its owners have lost interest in it.

Comment: You are correct.  The Xptr is destructed `v.erase(v.begin());`.  The Xptr destructor says "oh, there's another live Xptr to the X, so won't destruct it here.  All done, bye bye."

Comment: "**Destr X** prints shouldn't appear before **after erase**". You're right, they shouldn't, and they [don't](https://godbolt.org/z/EKKxe343P). What issue are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a `shared_ptr`, you have two references to both objects. These are `x` and `x2`, and the `shared_ptr`s inside vector `v`.

When you `erase()`, the destructor of `shared_ptr` is called, and the reference count is decremented, but still `1`. Therefore object `X` still exists.
After leaving the scope of `main()`, the count is decremented again. Now the count goes down to zero, and the destructor of object `X` is called.

Hence the output "after erase" is shown first, and only then "Destr X".

---

When you put `x` and `x2` in an inner scope, you will see the expected behaviour

```
std::vector<Xptr> v;

{
    std::shared_ptr<X> x = std::make_shared<X>();
    Xptr x2 = std::make_shared<X>();
    v.emplace_back(x);
    v.emplace_back(x2);
}

std::cout<<"before erase\n";
v.erase(v.begin());
std::cout<<"after erase\n";
```

Now you see

```
Contr X
Contr X
before erase
Destr X
after erase
Destr X
```

Answer (score 1):

*"As far as I know destructor is called when an element is erased from container..."*

That is correct. But when that element is a `std::shared_ptr` it is the `std::shared_ptr` whose destructor is called, not the destructor of whatever the `std::shared_ptr` is pointing to.

The `std::shared_ptr` will *only* call the destructor of the object it points to if it is the *last* `std::shared_ptr` pointing to it. But in your code you have `2` `std::shared_ptr`s pointing to each of the objects you created. You have one each in the `std::vector` and one each as local `std::shared_ptr` variables `x` and `x2` before they are added to the `std::vector`.

So when you delete the elements from the `std::vector` the `std::vector` delets the `std::shared_ptr`s it contains but the objects pointed to by those `std::shared_ptr`s are not destroyed until the `std::shared_ptr` variables `x` and `x2` go out of scope at the end of `main()`.